ICE Connection Fails to Complete in WebRTC Application on AWS EC2 Instance
I'm developing a WebRTC application where one of the peers is a backend server. The application works fine on localhost, with the ICE connection successfully established.
However, after deploying my backend server (which includes the signaling service and the peer) to an AWS EC2 instance, the ICE connection never completes.
Things I Have Tried:

TURN and STUN Servers: I am using TURN and STUN servers provided by
metered.ca.
Ports Configuration: I have opened all necessary UDP and
TCP ports on my EC2 instance required for WebRTC.
Verification: I have verified that the TURN and STUN servers are reachable from the EC2 instance.

Observations:

The application works fine on localhost, so the basic implementation
seems correct. The issue arises only when the backend server is
deployed to the AWS EC2 instance.

Question:
What could be causing the ICE connection to fail on the EC2 instance? Has anyone faced a similar issue, and how did you resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Client Peer (messages received)


sdp {"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 240022908004722204 989481823 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 ED:68:4A:BE:B4:57:06:52:12:32:76:C6:97:B4:E3:38:C3:D7:62:17:00:C4:82:6A:C6:91:E0:BC:C4:6F:1D:1B\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF
111 9 0 8\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:0\r\na=ice-ufrag:jyRLMFbLqPUgRphu\r\na=ice-pwd:BvOTXnDoGRlLZWJjOvbPlupBRxTXNsXl\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp-rsize\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtcp-fb:111
transport-cc\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=ssrc:3651177996 cname:webrtc-rs\r\na=ssrc:3651177996 msid:webrtc-rs track-audio\r\na=ssrc:3651177996
mslabel:webrtc-rs\r\na=ssrc:3651177996 label:track-audio\r\na=msid:webrtc-rs track-audio\r\na=sendrecv\r\nm=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=setup:active\r\na=mid:1\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=ice-ufrag:jyRLMFbLqPUgRphu\r\na=ice-pwd:BvOTXnDoGRlLZWJjOvbPlupBRxTXNsXl\r\n","type":"answer"}

{"candidate":"udp host 172.31.15.252:49434","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":null,"usernameFragment":null} {"candidate":"udp host 172.17.0.1:55449","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":null,"usernameFragment":null} 
{"candidate":"udp relay 139.59.19.18:560210.0.0.0","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":null,"usernameFragment":null}
{"candidate":"udp relay 139.59.19.18:359900.0.0.0","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":null,"usernameFragment":null} {"candidate":"udp srflx 13.233.20.77:488520.0.0.0","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":null,"usernameFragment":null}



13.233.20.77 is my ec2 instance's public ip which i can see in last candidate sent above to the client peer.
Server Peer (messages received)


sdp {"type":"offer","sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 3907482112097151524 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0 1\r\na=extmap-allow-mixed\r\na=msid-semantic: WMS 72d2cdcd-42e8-40aa-aea9-8b0a41952082\r\nm=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 9 0 8 13 110
126\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Ibni\r\na=ice-pwd:yV+xCsnzd9MPRffWcdfWJyfe\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 DB:DF:26:7B:55:84:BC:44:3D:C9:47:7C:C0:0D:DC:AD:57:A8:F2:83:58:D4:5A:B3:22:5B:D7:8D:5B:08:65:1F\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:0\r\na=extmap:1
urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level\r\na=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time\r\na=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01\r\na=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=msid:72d2cdcd-42e8-40aa-aea9-8b0a41952082
b6416a9b-c811-4d15-9368-1772be9bfaad\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2\r\na=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc\r\na=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1\r\na=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2\r\na=fmtp:63 111/111\r\na=rtpmap:9 G722/8000\r\na=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000\r\na=rtpmap:8
PCMA/8000\r\na=rtpmap:13 CN/8000\r\na=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000\r\na=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000\r\na=ssrc:1848777914 cname:vYV3Pu/m38Hrw8ZW\r\na=ssrc:1848777914 msid:72d2cdcd-42e8-40aa-aea9-8b0a41952082 b6416a9b-c811-4d15-9368-1772be9bfaad\r\nm=application
9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:Ibni\r\na=ice-pwd:yV+xCsnzd9MPRffWcdfWJyfe\r\na=ice-options:trickle\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 DB:DF:26:7B:55:84:BC:44:3D:C9:47:7C:C0:0D:DC:AD:57:A8:F2:83:58:D4:5A:B3:22:5B:D7:8D:5B:08:65:1F\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=mid:1\r\na=sctp-port:5000\r\na=max-message-size:262144\r\n"}

{"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3876928226 1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.11 54334 typ host generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}} {"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:3876928226
1 udp 2122260223 192.168.1.11 59055 typ host generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"1","sdpMLineIndex":1}} {"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2581256314 1 tcp 1518280447 192.168.1.11 9 typ host tcptype active
generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}} 
{"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1928205250 1 udp 41885951 139.59.19.18 38534 typ relay raddr 106.222.202.29 rport 22875 generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}} {"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:1928205250 1 udp 41886463 139.59.19.18 57046 typ relay raddr 106.222.202.29 rport 31043 generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost
10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}} {"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:203551066 1 udp 25108991 139.59.19.18 56509 typ relay raddr 106.222.202.29 rport 4510 generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}
{"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:4020057022 1 udp 8331263 139.59.19.18 60961 typ relay raddr 106.222.202.29 rport 25300 generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}} 
{"type":"candidate","candidate":{"candidate":"candidate:2817476683
1 udp 1686052607 106.222.202.29 12826 typ srflx raddr 192.168.1.11 rport 54334 generation 0 ufrag Ibni network-id 1 network-cost 10","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0}}




I've met the same problem on aws ec2, after searching, I find this answer, it said "make sure the firewall allows udp packets on all udp ports, as webrtc will pick random ports to send media and STUN packets", so after I add all upd ports to incoming rule of security group, it worked.
I think you can try below two solutions:

"opened all UDP", not "opened all necessary UDP", but I think this may add security risk
or set portRange in RTCPeerConnection option, then opened UDP ports within this range

Good Luck!
